# Bootstrap data interchange?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, data-interchange

Does anyone know if Bootstrap has support for anything similar to Foundation's Data Interchange plugin? Or any jQuery standalones that achieve the same effect?

I've done my usual and hidden sections of my site for mobiles, but I'm keen to avoid loading this section at all unless needed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added a repository that has the current version of bootstrap (3.3.5) using the foundation 5 interchange script. I was in the same boat trying to get that to work so I made this, hope it helps!

https://github.com/stolve/bootstrap-interchange

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, check out Adaptive Images (http://adaptive-images.com/), Response.js (http://responsejs.com/).  You could also always do a custom build with Data Interchange, pulling out the elements you need and incorporating them into Bootstrap; or DIY it with screen media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I forked the repo made by [@Stolve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/689083/stolve) and updated it to Bootstrap 4.

https://github.com/shadtek/bootstrap4-interchange